# iOS Status Bar over the content in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I have the problem that on my Ionic View there is no space to the top. So the iOS Status Bar lies over the ion-header. Unfortunately I couldn't test it on Android yet.

[image]

**This is my HTML-code:**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>spots</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

**and this in the app.ts:**

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code under the app.module

```
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
        platforms: {
            ios: {
              statusbarPadding: true,
              tabsHideOnSubPages: true
            }
          }
      })
```

This is the fix for the latest ionic 3.2.0